# Concurrently updating field data results in lost updates

Tags: 8, entities

I have a `field_whatever` (allows unlimited values) on the user entity and this API endpoint:

```yml
# mymodule.routing.yml
mymodule.foo:
  path: "/api/foo"
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Api::foo'
  methods: [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: "TRUE"
```

```php
# Api.php
  public function foo() {
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $user->get('field_whatever')->appendItem(\Drupal::request()->query->get('value'));
    $user->save();
    return new JsonResponse("", 204);
  }
```

I then issue these (obviously async) XHRs on my browser console in one go:

```js
fetch('/api/foo?value=111'); fetch('/api/foo?value=222'); fetch('/api/foo?value=333');
```

All of them return a 204, which, to the client should mean that every value was persisted. Unfortunately though, most of the times (99%) the ending value on the user's field will be just one of the three requests (e.g just `[333]` instead of `[111, 222, 333]`) and it'll be the one of the last transaction which committed.

By inspecting the queries via `set global general_log = 'ON';` I can confirm the lost update. The sequence for just one of the updates looks like this:

```
// reading of field value must happen here
...
START TRANSACTION
...
DELETE FROM user__field_whatever WHERE entity_id = '1'
INSERT INTO user__field_whatever (entity_id, ..., field_whatever_value) VALUES ('1', ..., '222'), ('1', ..., '333'), ...
...
COMMIT
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Things I've tried:

1. Make those XHRs sync but this is not appropriate since different clients or servers can hit my API concurrently.
2. Lock and let the client know that the update failed so they can retry:

```php
  try {
    $lock = \Drupal::lock();
    if ($lock->acquire('mymodule.foo')) {
      // do read, update, save here
    } else {
      return new JsonResponse("", 500); // throw some error code to let the client know that we did not update value so they can retry
    }
  } finally {
    $lock->release('mymodule.foo');
  }
  return new JsonResponse("", 204);
```

3. Wait until the lock can be acquired on the backend, so the client always succeeds and is unaware of the backend issue. This leads to complex backend code of course, and the serious possibility that a stale lock will lead to DOS in case a lot of backend threads end up waiting for the lock which will never be released.
4. Try to explicitly start a transaction as early as possible to make sure that the data is pulled from the database before the save:

```
$transaction = \Drupal::database()->startTransaction();
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
...
```

but the effect is exactly the same.

Is there another way?

Comment: Is User::load returning a cached object maybe?

Comment: Not sure. I don't see select queries to `user__field_whatever` so maybe it is.